# I want to Reverse a string in Java and drop and duplicates

Tags: java, string, byte, reverse

Converting String into Bytes: getBytes() method is used to convert the input string into bytes[].
Method:

1. Create a temporary byte[]  of length equal 
   to the length of the input string.
2. Store the bytes (which we get by using 
   getBytes() method) in reverse order into 
   the temporary byte[] .
3. Create a new String abject using byte[] to
   store result.

Source

```
// Java program to ReverseString using ByteArray. 
import java.lang.*; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 

// Class of ReverseString 
class ReverseString 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        String input = "Geeks"; 

        // getBytes() method to convert string  
        // into bytes[]. 
        byte [] strAsByteArray = input.getBytes(); 

        byte [] result =  
                   new byte [strAsByteArray.length]; 

        // Store result in reverse order into the 
        // result byte[] 
        for (int i = 0; i<strAsByteArray.length; i++) 
            result[i] =  
             strAsByteArray[strAsByteArray.length-i-1]; 

        System.out.println(new String(result)); 
    } 
}
```

I expect the output to be : **skeg**

Comment: where are you checking for duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I was looking for

```
    public class CodeExercise
```

{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input = "abbac";

    char[] strArr= input.toCharArray();

  String result = "";

  // Reverse
  for(int i = strArr.length -1; i>=0; i--){
      result = result + strArr[i];

  }
  result = removeDuplicate(result.toCharArray());
  System.out.println(new String(result));
}

 // Collapsing any adjacent duplicate characters
public static String removeDuplicate(char[] chars)
{
    char prev = '\0';
    int x = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
    {
        if (prev != chars[i]) {
            chars[x++] = chars[i];
            prev = chars[i];
        }
    }

    return new String(chars).substring(0, x);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the current byte, and not add the following byte if it be the same as the previous one:

```
String input = "Geeks";
byte[] strAsByteArray = input.getBytes(); 
List<Byte> list = new ArrayList<>();
//byte[] result = new byte[strAsByteArray.length];
byte prev = 0;

for (int i=0; i < strAsByteArray.length; i++) {
    byte curr = strAsByteArray[strAsByteArray.length-i-1];
    if (curr != prev) {
        prev = curr;
        list.add(curr);
    }
}

byte[] result = new byte[list.size()];
for (int i=0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
    result[i] = list.get(i);
}

System.out.println(new String(result));
```

This prints:

```
skeG
```

Note that I use a list to store the bytes initially, because we don't actually know what the final size of the fixed byte array will be until after we have parsed the entire string in reverse.  I wanted to find a sleek way to convert a `List<Byte>` to an array of primitive bytes using streams.  That failing, I just used an enhanced for loop.

Comment: and what if the duplicate is not consecutive?

Comment: @Kartik I don't see/interpret this requirement in the original question.  I will wait for the OP to also comment if I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Do nested loop.
This is without the use of a collection/list.
Place this after you created your result.

```
byte[] finalResult = new byte[result.length];
int k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    boolean hasDuplicates = false;

    for (int j = i + 1; j < result.length; j++) {
        if (result[i] == result[j]) {
            hasDuplicates = true;
        }
    }

    if (!hasDuplicates) {
           finalResult[k++] = result[i];
    }
}

System.out.println(new String(finalResult));
```

Example: welcome

Result: moclew

Not sure if this is your intended response.

---

There's a better way for this using only fewer loops.

Answer (score -2):

you simply need to convert your `byte[]`to a string using the following syntax:

```
System.out.println(new String(result, "UTF-8");
```